# Data Annotation to check an existing value in ID field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio, data-annotations

I have a model like this in an VS2013 Visual Basic MVC application:

```
Public Class ItemsMetadata
    <Key> _
    <Display(Name:="ID")> _
     Public ID As Integer

    <StringLength(50)> _
    <Display(Name:="Description")> _
    Public Desc As String
    ...
End Class
```

ID is a Primary key field and I want to add a Data Annotation to check if the entered value is unique.

If the user leaves the ID field empty, the correct error message appears ("Field is mandatory") but if an already existing ID is provided, the application crashes.

I have not found a Data Annotation that checks an existing value in a ID field, how can it be done?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If your wanting client side validation, then use the `[Remote]` attribute - refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx). But if ID is the PK, why are you having the user enter a value - it should be auto-incremeted in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I am a bit new to that, and my form had the ID field generated by VS. If I leave it empty it generates a validation error. Should I hide it? With a Data Annotation in the model?

Comment: If its an auto-generated ID property, then it should not be editable so if your creating a new object, then no input is required, and if your editing an existing object, then add a hidden input or add its value as a route parameter in the form

Comment: Should I add <ScaffoldColumn(False)> on top of the ID field then?

Comment: I have also hidden it in the form like this:

`@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.ID)`

but it does not auto increment the ID, simply `ModelState.IsValid` is false.
What do I do to make ID auto-increment? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: the ID field was Primary Key but not IDENTITY, so it was not automatically incremented.

Sorry for the overlook, thanks to all.